# ionCube Loader installation

Tags: ioncube

I am attempting to install ionCube on my VPS from OVH and I have ran the install and selected the appropriate options but then it simply returns a screen with the header of ionCube but then it has a banner saying "IMPORTANT: Ensure that This Script Is Removed When No Longer Required" followed by a single line of writing that says "ionCube Loader Wizard" and does nothing. In addition the application that it using ionCube says it is still not installed.

Comment: Can you post the output of your `phpinfo()` here, or link to the wizard script, as well as the relevant `zend_extension` line from your script? Could you also paste the exact error message from the script? If you don't want to expose any links/information, you can also open a ticket at http://support.ioncube.com . Keep in mind ionCube is UK based so their office hours begin in ~9 hours from this comment.

  [1]: http://support.ioncube.com

Comment: ok thanks a lot mate !